# Using comprehensions instead of a for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The following is a simplified example of my code.

```
>>> def action(num):
        print "Number is", num
>>> items = [1, 3, 6]
>>> for i in [j for j in items if j > 4]:
        action(i)
Number is 6
```

**My question is the following:** is it bad practice (for reasons such as code clarity) to simply replace the `for` loop with a comprehension which will still call the `action` function? That is:

```
>>> (action(j) for j in items if j > 2)
Number is 6
```

Comment: No it's not, it's actually nicer, and faster, I think, because it doesn't first create a lists and than loops over it, but that returns a list of `None`, because action doesn't return anything, and you'd use `[]` for list comp

Comment: That's actually a generator statement you got there, not a list comprehension. I don't know if that significantly affects your question, though.

Comment: @Tagc I know it creates a generator, wasn't sure if you'd call it a generator comprehension, but yeah same idea for a list comprehension. Would one be preferred over the other for any reason?

Comment: Personally I'm not decided to which way I'd prefer it. @willywonkadailyblah makes some good points but on the other hand, I imagine list comprehensions/generator expressions to, well, generate lists. It seems odd to use these constructs in situations where no list of objects is actually being generated. I don't use Python a lot and this is just my opinion - pretty open to what others have to say on the matter.

Comment: I think this question could benefit more from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't use a generator or comprehension at all.

```
def action(num):
    print "Number is", num

items = [1, 3, 6]
for j in items:
    if j > 4:
        action(i)
```

Generators evaluate lazily. The expression `(action(j) for j in items if j > 2)` will merely return a generator expression to the caller. Nothing will happen in it unless you explicitly exhaust it. List comprehensions evaluate eagerly, but, in this particular case, you are left with a `list` with no purpose. Just use a regular loop.

Comment: "List comprehensions evaluate eagerly, but, in this particular case, you are left with a list with no purpose. Just use a regular loop."

While others raised good points in favour, this is really a very strong argument *against* using generator expressions/list comprehensions. I'm going to chip in my upvote for this answer.

Comment: Is it particularly a bad idea to create a list 'with no purpose'?

Comment: @Siwel, of course. If you don't need anything, don't create it! Thus - better readability and faster code execution.

Answer (score 1):

While I personally favour [Tigerhawk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809404/1636276), there might be a middle ground between his and willywonkadailyblah's solution (now deleted).

One of willywonkadailyblah's points was:

> Why create a new list instead of just using the old one? You already have the condition to filter out the correct elements, so why put them away in memory and come back for them?

One way to avoid this problem is to use *lazy evaluation* of the filtering i.e. have the filtering done only when iterating using the for loop by making the filtering part of a generator expression rather than a list comprehension:

```
for i in (j for j in items if j > 4):
    action(i)
```

**Output**

```
Number is 6
```

In all honesty, I think Tigerhawk's solution is the best for this, though. This is just one possible alternative.

The reason that I proposed this is that it reminds me a lot of LINQ queries in C#, where you define a lazy way to extract, filter and project elements from a sequence in one statement (the LINQ expression) and can then use a separate `for each` loop with that query to perform some action on each element.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad practice. Firstly, your code fragment does not produce the desired output. You would instead get something like: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03D826F0>`.

Secondly, a list comprehension is for creating sequences, and generators a for creating streams of objects. Typically, they do not have side effects. Your action function is a prime example of a side effect -- it prints its input and returns nothing. Rather, a generator should for each item it generates, take an input and compute some output. eg.

```
doubled_odds = [x*2 for x in range(10) if x % 2 != 0]
```

By using a generator you are obfuscating the purpose of your code, which is to mutate global state (printing something), and not to create a stream of objects.
Whereas, just using a for loop makes the code slightly longer (basically just more whitespace), but immediately you can see that the purpose is to apply function to a selection of items (as opposed to creating a new stream/list of items).

```
for i in items:
    if i < 4:
        action(i)
```

Remember that generators are still looping constructs and that the underlying bytecode is more or less the same (if anything, generators are marginally less efficient), *and* you lose clarity. Generators and list comprehensions are great, but this is not the right situation for them.